# Revert a mistakenly approved Suggested Edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-page

I mistakenly approved a suggested edit. I wish to undo the approval, but I am not able to find any option to do so.

Is there a way I can do it myself? Or do I need to seek assistance of a site moderator?

I immediately navigated back and can see only a next button where the Approve, Reject and Edit buttons are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, this happens to all of us and therefore it's a good thing that Suggested Edits require two reviewers.

You [cannot change your decision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179612/295232), the system simply doesn't allow it. Even ♦ moderators cannot change your review, though of course we can review the suggested edits ourselves (just like two regular users would).

What you *could* do is navigate to the edit page of the post (`https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/<post id>/edit`) and improve the post yourself - this will reject the pending edit as conflicting with yours. Of course, this should only be done if there's actually anything to improve in the post.

Comment: Another unrelated question. When trying to accept your answer, I got a message stating "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes". What is causing it? I remember it takes some time before I can accept my own answer, but what is happening here?

Comment: That's by design: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44099/295232 For a self-answer, the limit is 48 hours instead of 15 minutes. You're much more likely to encounter those messages.

Comment: The question's ID is in the URL, after `/questions/`, e.g. `https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/revert...` -> post ID is 3560. For answers, either copy it over from the revisions list, or click 'share', which gives you `https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3561/121968`, the post ID is the first number, after `/a/`, so 3561.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails there is always the option of flagging a post for mod attention and including a message when flagging.